# Probability problem - Converse to SLLN

Tags: probability, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I'm having trouble with an exercise (E4.6 Converse to SLLN) in "Probability with Martingales" by David Williams. The problem is as follows:

Let $Z$ be a non-negative RV. Let $Y$ be the integer part of $Z$. Show that 
$$Y=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}I_{\{Z\ge n\}},$$
and deduce that 
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}P[Z\ge n]\le E[Z]\le 1+\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}P[Z\ge n].$$
Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of IID RVs (independent, identically distributed random variables) with $E[|X_n|]=\infty$, $\forall n$. Prove that
$$\sum_n P[|X_n|>kn]=\infty\ \ (k\in \mathbb{N})\ \ \text{and}\ \ \lim \sup \frac{|X_n|}{n}=\infty,\ \ \text{a.s.}$$
Deduce that if $S_n=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n,$ then 
$$\lim \sup \frac{|S_n|}{n}=\infty,\ \ \text{a.s.}\phantom{}$$

I have trouble with the last part about $S_n$. I was trying to relate $P[|S_n|>kn]$ with $P[|X_n|>kn]$ but I don't know how. I might not be on the right track. Could anybody take a look at this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From 
$${X_n\over n}={S_n\over n}-\left({n-1\over n}\right){S_{n-1}\over n-1},$$
we get 
$${|X_n|\over n}\leq {|S_n|\over n}+\left({n-1\over n}\right){|S_{n-1}|\over n-1},$$
and so 
$$\limsup_n {|X_n|\over n}\leq 2\limsup_n {|S_n|\over n}.$$
 Therefore $\limsup_n |X_n|/n=\infty$ implies $\limsup_n |S_n|/n=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem!

Comment: The last inequality is true, but it doesn't follow directly from the preceeding one. You need to be more careful when working with $\limsup$.